# no route matches service-worker.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I generated rails application and I got this message out of box. I don't know what service-worker.js is but I assume it can be bundled with some default gem?

```
Started GET "/service-worker.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-21 19:48:33 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/service-worker.js"):
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/emkacf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/emkacf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/emkacf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: How are you managing your javascript assets?

Comment: umm I have assets in standard /app/assets/ but this is just a fresh project generated from ruby mine that's why I am confused about this js file

Comment: That's a shot in the dark but did you forget to install node.js ?

Comment: Well I have installed node before because I was using ruby with rails before on that machine but my boyfriend did something with node and path on weekend (he was doing something and needet latest version but there were some problems) so maybe that will be the answer :D

Comment: I tried to reinstall node but it seems that it didn't help ;s

Comment: It worked after OS reinstall...

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296197/chrome-service-worker-process-running-on-port-3000)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that is from another application which uses webworkers. If you are using Firefox, go to menu > web developer > service workers and unregister webworker from there (That's the one way to do it). The other application will register it again if needed.

Answer (score 2):

This coming from client-side so it's from a service-worker that has been registered in the browser.

Open DevTools and run `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(r => r.unregister())` in your console to disable it.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed same problem by [this gem](https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails) .

1) Add `gem 'serviceworker-rails'` to **Gemfile**

2) Run `bundle install` in console

3) Run `rails g serviceworker:install` in console

4) Add `match '/offline.html'` string to **config/initializers/serviceworker.rb**

5) Create file (even empty will be enough) **public/offline.html**

Thats it. After these steps the error message gone.

Comment: There are enough challenges with service workers that just adding them to resolve this error doesn't make sense. The fact that something else has registered a service worker for that address is probably more useful.